# for loop provides only first or last result

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, return

At first I put the return inside the for loop but only the first result was getting displayed.
I've done some research and I realised that at result the loop was meeting the condition and therefore it was stopping at the first result.
I've taken it out of the loop and now it provides only the last result.
It's not the first time I've been having this issue and despite looking for a solution I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
function diamond(n) {


  let space = " "; //spaces
  let newLine = "\n"
  let aster = "*";
  let multi = (n - 1) / 2; //variable in for loop
  let result = ""

  if ((n % 2 === 0) || n < 1) {
    return null
  } else if (n === 1) {
    return aster
  } else {

    for (let i = 0; i < multi; i++) {
      result = space.repeat(multi - i) + aster.repeat(1 + (i * 2)) + space.repeat(multi - i) + newLine;
    }
    return result // gives only the last result
  }
}

console.log(diamond(7)) //  expected "  *\n ***\n*****\n ***\n  *\n"
console.log(diamond(1)) // expected "*"
console.log(diamond(2)) // expected null
```

Comment: try `result += ` instead of `result = `

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you reassign a new value at the variable `result` at each iteration of the loop.

You want to instanciate the variable first as a string.
Then concat datas to it at each iteration.

Something like this :

```
let result = '';
for (let i = 0; i < multi; i++) {
  result += space.repeat(multi - i) + aster.repeat(1 + (i * 2)) + space.repeat(multi - i) + newLine;
}
return result;
```

Pay attention to the `+=` operator :-)

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I've been stuck for a while and I couldn't figure it out! Now I understand what I was doing wrong! Have a nice evening!! :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have hinted, use `+=` to append each line to the result.

```js
function diamond(n) {


  let space = " "; //spaces
  let newLine = "\n"
  let aster = "*";
  let multi = (n - 1) / 2; //variable in for loop
  let result = ""

  if ((n % 2 === 0) || n < 1) {
    return null
  } else if (n === 1) {
    return aster
  } else {

    for (let i = 0; i < multi/2; ++i) {
      result += space.repeat(multi - i) + aster.repeat(1 + (i * 2)) + space.repeat(multi - i) + newLine;
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < multi/2 + 1; ++i) {
      result += space.repeat(i+1) + aster.repeat(1 + ((multi-1-i) * 2)) + space.repeat(i+1) + newLine;
    }
    return result // gives only the last result
  }
}

console.log(diamond(7)) //  expected "  *\n ***\n*****\n ***\n  *\n"
console.log(diamond(1)) // expected "*"
console.log(diamond(2)) // expected null
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I didn't realise i could use ```result +=``` in both and then have the result from both in one.